# How to send a mail with page which get parameters in php

Tags: php, email, parameters

I'm doing a code to send mails to users (from database).

The body (mesagge) is a page named **ContentEnvio.php** which recieve the user's `ID` and show like this:

[image]

The script to send the mails, has this code:

```
<?php


    $controller = 1;
    require_once "../controller/usuariosController.php";

    for ( $x=0; $x<count($Empleados); $x++) {

        $idusuario = $Empleados[$x]['id'];

        $empleado_env = utf8_encode($Empleados[$x]['usuario']);
        $empleado = explode(",", $empleado_env);

        $asunto = "ACTIVIDADES PENDIENTES - " .$empleado[1];


        $postdata = http_build_query(
            array(
                'idusuario' => $idusuario
            )
        );

        $opts = array('http' =>
            array(
                'method'  => 'GET',
                'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => $postdata
            )
        );

        $context  = stream_context_create($opts);


        // CONFIGURACION:
        $maildestinatario = $Empleados[$x]['correo'];
        $de = "AppsLovers - Project Manager";
        $desde = "pm@appslovers.com";


        $cabecera = 'From: '.$de . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: '.$desde . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        $cabecera.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        mail($maildestinatario, $asunto, file_get_contents("../test/ContentEnvio.php", false, $context), $cabecera);


    }

?>
```

It doesn't show any error. I tested in my e-mail and i have the mail received, but .... the content looks like this:

[image]

Do i have to add any other syntax?

Comment: Cause file_get_contents reads the file into a string. You need the output in the email, not all the code.

Comment: Not yet, I recieved a blank message. I'm trying to make other ways to do the script.

Answer (score 1):

You could try including the php file and only collect the html it generates. Something similar to:

```
ob_start(); // Start 

require_once('../test/ContentEnvio.php');

$html = ob_get_clean(); // Get it to the variable

mail($maildestinatario, $asunto, $html, $cabecera);
```

In the "From" header you should put the name ahead of an email...like:

```
$de = "AppsLovers - Project Manager <noreply@appslovers.com>";
```

Comment: I was literally seconds from finishing writing the same thing. :)

Comment: Typo: you are missing the second comment slash on the third line.

Comment: And how can i pass my variable `idusuario` to the `ContentEnvio.php` to show data?

Comment: Is there any problem if i put `require_once` inside a `for` ? ... Now, I have in my e-mail address a blank message.

Comment: @JhonatanSandoval Since you're including the ContentEnvio.php script, you should just be able to dynamically set any variables needed to get the right output. From what I can tell by reading your "email", you're using $idusuario from the GET you're passing in the url, so just leave that variable alone, it should do.

require_once, will only work once, so no you'd have to use "require" instead inside a for loop.